# Can Google Play Game Services be used for PC games? (Windows/Linux/OSX)

Tags: c++, windows, google-play-games

Can Google Play Game Services be used for PC games out of the box?

Currently I am pondering the idea about doing standalone release (not on Steam), and instead of creating our own leaderboards/achievements system, I would rather use something that already exists. Google Play Service came to mind and thus I got this question. The game is written in C++ and currently runs on Windows/Linux (OSX support is planned for post-release)

Thanks.

Comment: There are several factors here: (1) Is it technically possible?  A: Certainly.  These OSes expose to C++ the capability to construct any network traffic which might be required.  Hypothetically there could be some cryptographic challenge which could only be answered by an Android device, but the availability of emulators rules that out.  (2) Is it permitted?  A. That's a policy, not programming question, and off-topic here.  (3) Does google supply Google Play integration libraries for use on these OSes?  Presumably this last is what you are hoping to learn?

Comment: In essence, yes, I am asking if such approach is permitted by the policy and if there are libs that would work on Windows/Linux/OSX. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use the REST api.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/gettingstarted

There is even a Google published JAVA api that is used for desktop access that uses the REST api.

Answer (score -1):

No, the Google Play Service is intended for games developed for Android, iOS and the Web.

Details are found here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/

Comment: That's just not true - Games Services are [documented](https://developers.google.com/games/services/) to work with iOS games too, for a start.

Answer (score -1):

yes, it is possible you get installed android pc games application. then installed  Google Play Game from your PC any Windows/Linux/OSX. get enjoy.